# Render a Collection of Text Fields which is passed to Doctrine array field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

In my entity i have an array field:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="work_experience", type="array")
 */
private $workExperience;
```

now i want to render a collection of text fields which will be passed to this array field.

```
->add('workExperience', 'collection', array(
                'type'         => 'text',
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype'    => true,
                #'by_reference' => false,
                'options'  => array(
                    'required'  => false,
                    'attr'      => array('class' => 'line-box')
                ),
            ))
```

but now when i render this field, no input is shown? What is my mistake?

```
{{ form_row(form.workExperience) }}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show `print_r($form->createView());` from your controller?

Comment: You need to embed another form which makes a collection element. That is `'type'=>new YourFormToBeEmbeddedType(),` and not `'type'=>'email'`.

Comment: Here we go:

http://leadvertise.de/output.html

Comment: the symfony2 docs are saying that its also possible without entities:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

in the example they easily use email field type

Answer (score 1):

When prototyping, the collection field(s) is only render if your entity has a value assigned to `workExperience` inside your controller, Otherwise you would need to use javascript to take the prototype info and create the input field(s), this is also true if you want to add new field(s) with or without your entity having any value.

To get the following to render with values

```
{{ form_row(form.workExperience) }}
```

You can do something like the following:

```
public function controllerAction(Request $request)
{
    //By populating your entity with values from your database
    //workExperience should receive a value and be rendered in your form.
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em
       ->getRepository('yourBundle:entity')
       ->findBy(...yourParameters...);


$form = $this->createForm('your_form_type', $entity);
...
```

Or

```
...
//If you do not have any data in your database for `workExperience` 
//then you would need to set it in your controller.

$arr = array('email' => 'name@company.com', 'phone' => '888-888-8888');
$entity->setWorkExperience($arr);
$form = $this->createForm('your_form_type', $entity);
...
```

Keep in mind that collection are usually used for one-to-many or many-to-many relationships.
Using it for array can be done but there is not much documented on it. While this link is not a perfect fit, the general ideas presented many be helpful: [form_collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)